# Create object in server JS

Tags: javascript, iis, asp-classic

I try to do on classic asp page:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My ASP Page</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="white">

<script language="JScript" runat="server"> 
    var oWeb = GetObject("IIS://localhost/W3SVC"); 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It throws error: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Permission denied"

What should I do, what permission and where to add?

Comment: I think the first step should be [installing ADSI Edit tool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773354(v=ws.10).aspx).

Comment: How to install it on Windows 7 or 2008 Server ?

Comment: Under "Installing ADSI Edit" it says *To install ADSI Edit on computers running Windows Vista® with Service Pack 1 (SP1) **or Windows 7**, you must install RSAT. For more information and to download RSAT, see article 941314 in the Microsoft Knowledge Base (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=116179)*

Comment: Ok, I installed RSAT on my Windows 7, and what next ?

Comment: Didn't install it myself so far, try to grant permissions through it - will take better look tomorrow.